# Using standard style css in React and JSX

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

I have css below.

in `myCss.css`

```
.playlist { margin: 200 200; }
.playlist .channel { background: grey; }
```

and in JSX

```
import "./myCss.css"
.
.

render (){
  return (
    <div className="playlist" id="playlist">
    </div>
  )
}
```

It doesn't work. OK maybe I need some special way to JSX.

I googled around and found some ways like `styled component`.

However I want to use normal css way because some parameters like `.playlist .channnel` is generated by library in the   `<div className="playlist" id="playlist">`.

So I can't change.

I want to stick with normal css in React and JSX.

Is it impossible???

Comment: What does "It doesn't work" mean? What bundler are you using? React doesn't know about how your CSS is handled. Do you see the class applied in the rendered DOM when you inspect it?

Comment: this will work in a create-react-app project

Comment: Please be more specific about what isn't working as it seems to work as I would expect it to in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/using-standard-style-css-in-react-and-jsx-iw2jv).

Comment: I miss-understood something.some attribute work and other s not. maybe overrided somewhere. This project is a part of big project. I will check around once again.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are your bundler is not loading the css file.  If you are using Webpack, have a look at `css-loader` - https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/

Aside, `styled-components` is excellent, and you could use it along side your 'standard' css.  You could define your 'standard' css using `createGlobalStyle` - https://styled-components.com/docs/api#createglobalstyle and use the `styled` api for everything else.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and suggestion. I found out that my css is overrided later.  I am planning to learn styled-components later.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe problem with

```
.playlist { margin: 200 200; }
```

First of all, you need to specify **px**. It becomes:

```
.playlist { margin: 200px 200px; }
```

Second of all, you remove second *200*. Since it has no sense.

```
.playlist { margin: 200px; }
```

Comment: I see it might also the problem. I need to recheck the css digit.